# R loop for fuction until special value is reached

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, while-loop, cycle

Sorry, but I totally suck with for/while loops.

How can I correctly write the loop function until needed value is reached?
Basically I have this kind of function:

```
kendall(QK(1, B_6x6, 0.1), correct = TRUE)$value
kendall(QK(2, B_6x6, 0.1), correct = TRUE)$value
kendall(QK(3, B_6x6, 0.1), correct = TRUE)$value
.....etc.
```

but I need it to run untill this value will be equal 1.

like..

```
for (i in 1:99) {
kendall(QK(i, B_6x6, 0.1), correct = TRUE)$value
}
```

But how to correctly express this condition, so I could know which i this condition is reached?
Thank you very much for any input!

Comment: Assign the value to `v` and test `if(abs(v - 1) < .Machine$double.eps^0.5) break`

Comment: Instead of looping with a fixed step, an approximation (e.g. the venerable secant method) might be faster. Package {cmna} provides this and other algos: `cmna::secant(f = function(x){
  kendall(QK(x, B_6x6, 0.1), correct = TRUE)$value - 1
}, 
x = meaningful_start_value,  
tol = .01, ## desired tolerance
m = 20 ## max iterations
)`